# Como programar para abrir um tipo arquivo especifico?

Tags: java, arquivo

Gostaria aprender a mexer com arquivos, bom por exemplo programar em `java` e trabalhar com arquivo `CBR`, aqueles arquivos **HQ** ou **Gibi**

Para isso existe bibliotecas especifica para cada arquivo ou classe prontas ou melhor teria como criar uma classe para esse fim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um arquivo `.cbr` é um arquivo rar. Dentro do pacote estao um monte de arquivos de imagem. Você pode usar qualquer ferramentas/utilitários que você usaria normalmente para arquivos RAR/ZIP para entrar nos arquivos e lidar com as imagens diretamente.